# Error injecting a class with generic type @Inject Guice

Tags: java, generics, dependency-injection, guice, inject

I am trying to inject a class of Generic type (say ClassA) in another class (say ClassB) using Guice with @Inject annotation. The code of the class that is being injected is shown below:

```
public interface InterfaceA<T> {

}

public class ClassA<T> implements InterfaceA<T> {
    private final Class<T> data;
    private Dependency1 dependency1;

    @Inject
    public ClassA(Class<T> data, Dependency1 dependency1) {
        this.data = data;
        this.dependency1 = dependency1;
    }

}
```

Code of ClassB is as follows:

```
public class ClassB {
    private InterfaceA<Entity1> interfaceA;

    @Inject
    public ClassB(InterfaceA<Entity1> interfaceA) {
        this.interfaceA = interfaceA;
    }
}
```

The module class is as follows:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(new TypeLiteral<InterfaceA<Entity1>>(){}).to(new TypeLiteral<InterfaceA<Entity1>>(){});
    }
}
```

However, when the application starts, it is giving the following error:

```
ERROR [2017-01-14 19:54:00,646] com.hubspot.dropwizard.guice.GuiceBundle: Exception occurred when creating Guice Injector - exiting
! com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:
! 
! 1) Could not find a suitable constructor in java.lang.Class. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
!   at java.lang.Class.class(Class.java:119)
```

Any inputs on how to solve this would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to inject `Class<T>` into something? Isn't the whole point that you'll know the type in the module?

Comment: I want to inject it because I want to know to type of the class injected at runtime.

Comment: That seems to go against the point of OO programming. Also all classes have a `.getClass` method, that isn't sufficient?

Comment: How will you use `.getClass` method in the above scenario? I would like to know :)

Comment: I don't want to post this as an answer because there's a good chance I'm not understanding you, but I was referring to something like `public ClassA(Dependency1 dependency) { this.data = dependency.getClass(); /* etc. */ }`

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this in a declarative way. You have to use provider methods:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override protected void configure() {}

  @Provides InterfaceA<Entity1> provideInterfaceAEntity1(Dependency1 dep) {
    return new ClassA<Entity1>(Entity1.class, dep);
  }
}
```

This is the only way because you can't automagically inject `Class<T>` in `ClassA`.

You need such a method in your `Module` for each `Entity` you want to couple with `InterfaceA`.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! However, in this case, we are moving all the dependencies of ClassA outside of that class, which doesn't seem to be a clean way. Also, we are not using Guice's @Inject functionality here, but creating a new object using new(). I found another way to do this. Check out my solution.

Comment: @user3375226 Using `new` isn't forbidden with Guice. Using `@Inject` isn't even mandatory. Even more, Guice recommends that a constructor requests the final object. With `literal.getRawType()`, you break that recommendation. I believe this solution to be the most Guice-y.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out the solution. Here, instead of injecting `Class<T> data` in ClassA's constructor, I am injecting `TypeLiteral<T> literal` and reading the class type from TypeLiteral using it's `getRawType()` method.

Code for ClassA is as follows:

```
public class ClassA<T> implements InterfaceA<T> {
    private final Class<? super T> data;
    private Dependency1 dependency1;

    @Inject
    public ClassA(TypeLiteral<T> literal, Dependency1 dependency1) {
        this.data = literal.getRawType();
        this.dependency1 = dependency1;
    }
}
```

The rest of the code for other classes remains same as before.